# Implement Security::Hash from Cakephp in nodejs

Tags: node.js, cakephp, hash

so I have a login method in CakePHP using `Security::hash($password, NULL, true)`, and I'd like to implement this in NodeJS.
I tried this:

```
    var sha1 = function(password, salt){
      password = salt + password;
      var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha1', ''); /** Hashing algorithm sha1 */
      hash.update(password);
      var value = hash.digest('hex');
      console.log(value);
      return {
          salt:salt,
          passwordHash:value
      };
  };
```

but the result hash is different from what Cake gave me. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it !

```
    var hash_sha1 = function(password, salt){
    password = salt + password;
    var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1'); /** Hashing algorithm sha1 */
    hash.update(password);
    var value = hash.digest('hex');
    return value;
};
```

Made a little gist about it : https://gist.github.com/Wats0ns/bb6210d4bfb4e0ce9d8db41750661363